# Are there new device identifiers in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, ios10

Has anyone found a new way to uniquely identify a device in iOS 10? I haven't seen any documentation mentioning changes in that area and I wanted to ask before I surrendered to identifier for vendor.

Comment: Apple made it very clear that you will not have acces to a unique device identifier, manly because you should identify the user not his/hers device. Using a device identifier is a breach of users privacy.

Answer (score 1):

If you're submitting to the store, the only real identifier you have left is the Advertising Identifier for the AdSupport framework.

If you want to go down the rabbit hole a little further and potentially go into some unsafe API territory, you could hook into IOKit and try to get the battery identifier on the device.  This is taken from Anthony Agatiello [gist](https://gist.github.com/anthonya1999/708bb747c1e7e4827b04b76f53ef7f28) of `UIDevice` extensions:

```
- (NSString *)batteryID {
    void *IOKit = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit", RTLD_LAZY);
    NSParameterAssert(IOKit);

    mach_port_t *kIOMasterPortDefault = dlsym(IOKit, "kIOMasterPortDefault");
    NSParameterAssert(kIOMasterPortDefault);
    CFMutableDictionaryRef (*IOServiceNameMatching)(const char *name) = dlsym(IOKit, "IOServiceNameMatching");
    NSParameterAssert(IOServiceNameMatching);
    mach_port_t (*IOServiceGetMatchingService)(mach_port_t masterPort, CFDictionaryRef matching) = dlsym(IOKit, "IOServiceGetMatchingService");
    NSParameterAssert(IOServiceGetMatchingService);
    kern_return_t (*IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties)(mach_port_t entry, CFMutableDictionaryRef *properties, CFAllocatorRef allocator, UInt32 options) = dlsym(IOKit, "IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties");
    NSParameterAssert(IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties);
    kern_return_t (*IOObjectRelease)(mach_port_t object) = dlsym(IOKit, "IOObjectRelease");
    NSParameterAssert(IOObjectRelease);

    CFMutableDictionaryRef properties = NULL;

    mach_port_t service = IOServiceGetMatchingService(*kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceNameMatching("charger"));
    IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(service, &properties, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);

    IOObjectRelease(service);
    service = 0;

    NSDictionary *dictionary = (__bridge NSDictionary *)properties;
    NSData *batteryIDData = [dictionary objectForKey:@"battery-id"];

    CFRelease(properties);
    properties = NULL;

    dlclose(IOKit);

    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[batteryIDData bytes]];
}
```

This still works on iOS 10.

Comment: what do you mean with unsafe api ? what's the problem to use batteryID ?

Comment: @david Apple really doesn't want developers to be able to identify a specific device.  This code manually opens a private framework (IOKit) and uses an undocumented function in that framework to get a battery identifier.  While I haven't to release an app to the store that uses this, Apple might reject your app.

Comment: @JAL I run the code in ios 10.0.1. It doesn't work. I get the value of properties. `Printing description of dictionary:
{
    "device_type" = <63686172 67657200>;
    name = <63686172 67657200>;
}`. It doesn't work anymore?