# Could use identifierforvendor as identifier?

Tags: ios10, identifier

follow this document. identifierforvendor is unique on the same app on the same device.

I want to ask. Is identifierforvendor unique each device?

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

UUID is unique for each device for your applicaion. But it will be changed if user uninstalls your application. So lets say User installed your application and you get their UUID and it was abc123 or something. Now If they un-install an re-install your application. You will not get the same UUID as before. If you want to use UUID for identifying the user. Detecting whether this user previously installed your application or not requires you to use keychain.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not unique any more ? If you install you app on a real device and then check its UUID after 2 days is it changed ?

Comment: Do not test in simulator because its change UUID very frequently

Comment: follow this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101380/are-there-new-device-identifiers-in-ios-10 . My product on IOS10, Many devices have the same UUID.